# When I enter correct username and password it refreshes the page

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a very simple username and password validation for practice.
In my page I hid a upload image form with css using`visibility: hidden;`
Here is my HTML code:

```
<form id="enter"  method="POST" action="" >
        <p style="padding:0px;" >Username:</p>
        <input type="text" name="" id="user" placeholder="Username" required>
        <p style="padding:0px; margin-top: 10px;" >Password:</p>
        <input type="password" name="" id="pass" placeholder="Password" required>
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Login" onclick="javascript:validate()">
        </form>
```

When I enter Username and Password I want upload image form to appear. As you can see, I tried to use some JavaScript on it. Code:

```
   function validate()
{
if(document.getElementById("user").value == "test" && document.getElementById("pass").value == "123" )

{
   
   document.getElementById('uploadForm').style.visibility = "visible";        
}
else
{
    alert( "Access Denied" );
}
}
```

The thing is when I enter correct username and password it refreshes the page. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: submit buttons submit so the page submits.. (and I hope you know this is not secure)

Comment: Yes i know it's not secure but thanks for warning anyway. How can I make this button don't submit?

Comment: you either cancel the action, cancel the form submission, or do not use a submit button.

Comment: Hey I just found out that if you change input from 'submit' to 'button'. It stops refreshing.

Comment: because a button is not a submit button. ;) Other ways to learn about are preventDefault and returning false.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is doing the default of submitting when you click the button.

This normally includes a POST sent, and then a refresh to get the next page, but with client-side form handling, you need to do one of two things to prevent this default submit:

1. Your function `validate()` can be updated to take an event object as a parameter, to then call [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) on.
2. You can `return false` from that onclick funciton, which will prevent further action
3. You can change it from a "submit" type input to a `<button type=button>`. *(Not recommended for accessibility reasons)*